# Flask at runtime: App not opening in browser from SSH terminal of Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python-3.x, flask, ssh, google-cloud-platform

I installed flask and wrote a simple flask code in VM instance of Google Cloud Platform (GCP).

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return "Welcome!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

When I run this code from SSH terminal of GCP I got following result.

```
root@instance-1:~# python3 app.py
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I tried using the WSGI server and still flask app is not opening in the browser when I click on running server link. I have added the necessary firewall rule also. What exactly be the reason behind it as I am just a beginner in GCP?

This are my firewall rule settings

[image: Firewall Rule]

Comment: What do you have configured for egress rules?

Comment: What URL are you using to access flask? Are you trying to access `http://0.0.0.0:8080/`?

Comment: @Kenster Yes in this example I was trying to access with the url http://0.0.0.0:8080/. I had also tried changing host to 127.0.0.1 and still doesn't work. Also opening from internal ip of gcp doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have attached the screenshot of the Firewall rule. Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: You posted an `ingress` rule (inbound). There is also an `egress` rule for outbound traffic.

Comment: @JohnHanley all outbound traffic is allowed in egress rule.

Comment: Try running 'http:// YOUR_INSTANCE_IP:8080' instead. Also, I can suggest having a quick look at [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/tutorials/getting-started-on-compute-engine)

Comment: Your app is listening on all interfaces on port 8080. This is OK. Your ingress and egress security groups are OK. The only items left are 1) Is the app actually running and listening on port 8080. Run this command and check for port 8080 in a listening state and for which interfaces: `netstat --listen`. 2) Double check that you are trying to access the VM using the correct Public IP address. The address `0.0.0.0` is not a public IP address. It is a parameter that tells the IP protocol libraries to listen on all network interfaces.

Comment: @JohnHanley I changed the `0.0.0.0` to `localhost(127.0.0.1)`. Also app is running and listening on port 8080 `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17803/python3`. Also accessing from instance ip address doesn't works.

Comment: localhost and 127.0.0.1 are NOT public IP addresses. They only exist inside the machine. Look up the public IP address for your VM in the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: You won't be able to see your web if you access 0.0.0.0 from your browser if you are running the website in your VM, why? Think on your VM as a server running a web app. If you want to access a server hosting a web page you enter an url wich is the equivalent to an ip address (in a simplified view of the task) so, for this case you need to do the same, access your VM using the Public ip of the machine.

Comment: @JohnHanley I think I have already specified about VM instance IP. Isn't that the public ip of the machine? Here is the screenshot of that. [link](https://imgur.com/a/vl0qvZC)